# add prefix to spark rdd elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two string elements in my rdd as :
    "53 45 61","0 1 2".
I would like to zip and map it together as Key value pair ,adding a prefix "C" to each of keys

expected output:

```
C53 -> 0, C45-> 1, C61-> 2
```

Currently this is the code I am using

```
val prefix = "C"

newRDD = RDD.map(x=>(prefix + (x._1.split(" ")) zip x._2.split(" "))
```

receiving result below:

```
53 -> 0, C45-> 1, 61-> 2 .
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're currently adding your prefix to an `Array(53, 45, 61)` (didn't know you could do that). Do you mean to do `x._1.split(" ").map(prefix + _)` to add it to each element instead?